# Database script failing while executing in dbmaintain

Tags: database, deployment, continuous-deployment

I am trying to execute simple `ddl` file during build. We've configure [dbmaintain](http://www.dbmaintain.org/overview.html) in our project for deploying database related stuff. However query's from ddl file is executing successfully, when executed in sql developer. But in build it's failing due to below error.

```
Error Message
Last statement in script was not ended correctly. Each statement should end with one of [;, /]
Stacktrace
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Last statement in script was not ended correctly. Each statement should end with one of [;, /]
    at org.unitils.dbmaintainer.script.impl.DefaultScriptParser.getNextStatementImpl(DefaultScriptParser.java:160)
    at org.unitils.dbmaintainer.script.impl.DefaultScriptParser.getNextStatement(DefaultScriptParser.java:93)
    at org.unitils.dbmaintainer.script.impl.DefaultScriptRunner.execute(DefaultScriptRunner.java:59)
    at org.unitils.dbmaintainer.DBMaintainer.executeScripts(DBMaintainer.java:342)
    at org.unitils.dbmaintainer.DBMaintainer.updateDatabase(DBMaintainer.java:303)
    at org.unitils.dbmaintainer.DBMaintainer.updateDatabase(DBMaintainer.java:250)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.updateDatabase(DatabaseModule.java:294)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.createDataSource(DatabaseModule.java:353)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.getDataSource(DatabaseModule.java:226)
    at org.unitils.orm.jpa.util.JpaEntityManagerFactoryLoader.getDataSource(JpaEntityManagerFactoryLoader.java:83)
    at
```

I tried entering semicolon at end of each statement but still the issue persist.
Below is my ddl file `001_create_req_tables.ddl`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ref_id_seq_ls;

CREATE TABLE LABEL_SOURCE_PRODUCTS(
REF_ID                      NUMBER(20)      NOT NULL, 
EAN_CODE                    VARCHAR2(255)   NOT NULL, 
CRY_ID                      VARCHAR2(10)    NOT NULL, 
IS_LABEL_SOURCE             VARCHAR2(1)     NOT NULL,
ACCOUNT_IDENTIFIER          VARCHAR2(4000),
CREATED_BY                  VARCHAR2(20), 
LAST_UPDATED_BY             VARCHAR2(20),
CREATED_ON                  DATE,
LAST_UPDATED_ON             DATE
);

CREATE TABLE ACTIVATE_FEATURE(
REF_ID                      NUMBER(20)      NOT NULL,
FEATURE_NAME                VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
IS_ACTIVE_FEATURE           VARCHAR2(1)     NOT NULL,
CREATED_BY                  VARCHAR2(20), 
LAST_UPDATED_BY             VARCHAR2(20),
CREATED_ON                  DATE,
LAST_UPDATED_ON             DATE
);

CREATE TRIGGER LS_LABEL_SOURCE_PRODUCTS
BEFORE INSERT ON LABEL_SOURCE_PRODUCTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT ref_id_seq_ls.nextval
  INTO :new.REF_ID
  FROM dual;
END;
```

Can someone please guide me through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because dbmaintain is not able to properly separate commands in your `001_create_req_tables.ddl`. According to the [documentation](http://www.dbmaintain.org/tutorial.html#PLSQL_support):

> Blocks of PL/SQL code must always end with a separate line containing a single forward slash.

In your case, it should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LS_LABEL_SOURCE_PRODUCTS
BEFORE INSERT ON LABEL_SOURCE_PRODUCTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT ref_id_seq_ls.nextval
  INTO :new.REF_ID
  FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Comment: Exactly!, this was the issue. Thanks